# Print image from filepath in Twig

Tags: 8, theming, media

I have a paragraph with an image field. If the image field is empty, I want to display a default value. I do *not* want to just set the default image because an editor could remove that. Here is my code so far:

```
{% if content.field_image|render = true %}
    {{ content.field_image }}
{% else %}
    {% include "/themes/mytheme/img/my_img.png” %}
{% endif %}
```

How can I get the image at that filepath to show up in the template?

Comment: You might be overthinking it - remember it's an HTML template, you can just use an `<img>` tag

Comment: @clive is the image path relative or does it need a root path? I attempted a relative path but it didn’t work. The relative path is something like “../../../img/my_img.png”

Comment: @Clive this was the answer. Wanna make your comment into an answer so I can give it to you?

Answer (score 1):

For example if your default image called `default_img.png` inside `images` folder inside your theme `MyTheme`.

You can try the following:

1. implement [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x)

```
/**
 2. Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function extended_url_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {
  $variables['theme_path'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'MyTheme');
}
```

3. In your twig you can do something like:

```html
{% if content.field_image|render = true %}  
    {{ content.field_image }}  
{% else %}  
<img src="{{ theme_path ~ directory }}/images/default_img.png"/>
{% endif %}
```